# Dynamic session array remove specific element

Tags: arrays, session, asp-classic, vbscript

So I am trying to remove a specific element from my dynamic session array. My current array removes the wrong element and leaves the element I wish to get rid of

```
sku = "the_item_value"
sessionArray = session("cart")
Dim length : length = Ubound(sessionArray)
sessionArray(length-1)=sku
ReDim Preserve sessionArray(length-1)
session("cart") = sessionArray
```

So this is my current code, it removes a single item from my session array. However, it does not remove the "sku" item, it removes a random item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The logic in your sample code does the following:

1. Replaces the second to last item with sku.

   `sessionArray(length-1)=sku`
2. Removes the last item.

   `ReDim Preserve sessionArray(length-1)`

This is obviously not what you want.  Instead, you need logic to find the sku item and then get rid of it.

If the order of the items does not matter, you could do something like this:

```
Sub RemoveArrayItem(array, item)
    ' Find item
    For i = LBound(array) To UBound(array)-1
        If array(i) = item Then
            ' Replace the item with last item
            array(i) = array(UBound(array))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    ' Remove the last item which is either a duplicate or it is the item
    ' (assuming that the item is definitely in the array)
    ReDim Preserve array(UBound(array)-1)
End Sub

sku = "the_item_value"
sessionArray = session("cart")

RemoveArrayItem sessionArray, sku

session("cart") = sessionArray
```

Comment: +1 But assumes LBound = 1 which is not necessarily true, replace with `LBound(sessionArray)` also length can be misleading if the array doesn't have LBound of 1.  Since `UBound` is cheap and `length` is used only twice I'd remove the variable altogether.  Finally consider restructuring to a `Sub` to create a general re-usable "RemoveArrayItem" operation.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Good catch.  My VBScript is a bit rusty.  Updated the answer to incorporate your fixes/suggestions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want exclude item(s) using value, you should use [Filter](http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_filter.asp) function.
Have a look:

```vb
Dim myArray, sku, myFilteredArray
sku = "the_item_value"
myArray = Array("other", "other", "other", sku)
Response.Write "Original:<br />" & Join(myArray, "<br />") 'check original
myFilteredArray = Filter(myArray, sku, False, vbBinaryCompare)
Response.Write "<hr />"
Response.Write "Excluded:<br />" & Join(myFilteredArray, "<br />") 'check filtered
```